# Why aren't my Kalanchoes blooming all at once?

Tags: houseplants, flowers, kalanchoe

I planted these different colored Kalanchoes in the same vase hoping I will get colorful blooms but while the orange one is in almost full bloom the white and the yellow have not even started yet. I was wondering if there is something I could do to encourage them bloom at the same time next season or is this their natural way of blooming and I should just plant them in different vases? 
[image]

One of the red ones that has just started blooming
[image]

And the yellow, pink, white, and the other red look like they need a couple more weeks
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try misting the unopened flowers with water,but essentially, when the blooms open on a plant is variable and exact accuracy about when they will open is not possible. All your Kalanchoe plants are at the blooming stage, and all will open up probably within the next few days.